# Error adding parameters to SQL Server stored procedure though VB code?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters

I am struggling to pass though parameter to a stored procedure I have written.

I’m really not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I’m struggling to get VB to pass parameters to SQL Server.

[image]

[image]

I am setting the `@m_id` above??

Comment: Can you post all the code in the file that is throwing the exception? It appears you have a different command (`cmd3`) being built when an exception happens, which is not the ideal way to handle the logic to build different commands. Using `structured exception handling` to control logic flow in your application is asking for trouble.

Comment: @karl Thanks, i will look to touch that up now, i also agree that the flow is asking for trouble. It is working now thanks to George Johnston answer below, but i will neaten up and order the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go out on a limb (because I don't see it in the above code) and say it's because you didn't set the `cmd2.CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`.  By default, the command type is `Text`, which is used for inline SQL.